# How to keep everything and nothing (specify in dictionary table)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the proper way to say everything and nothing in a dictionary table?

**For example**, for `key11`, I keep only `.txt` and `.doc` files. How do I specify for `key12`, to keep every (any) filetypes, and for `key13` to keep no filtypes (keep nothing)?

```
config = {
    ' key11': {},
    ' key12': {},
    ' key13': {},
}
config['key11']['files_to_keep'] = ('txt', 'doc')
config['key12']['files_to_keep'] = ('"*"')
config['key13']['files_to_keep'] = ()
```

Comment: That depends on how you continue to use those values. As it stands, the dictionary can contain anything and you are totally free to interpret the values any way you want.

Comment: It's up to you what to define as instructions. `*` is widely known for everything. To keep nothing, I would say hold `None` or an empty string `''`. Anyway, this question is subjective to you and there is no right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to think of how it is supposed to work instead.
For instance to filter out specific file-endings we could use this:

Note that we don't need to use any extra logic (if-statements) because the string already represents it.

```
config = {
    'key11': {},
    'key12': {},
    'key13': {},
}

config['key11']['files_to_keep'] = ('txt', 'doc') # txt.doc
config['key12']['files_to_keep'] = ('')  # All
config['key13']['files_to_keep'] = ('*') # None as strings don't end with *


files = ['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Text1.txt',
     'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Doc1.doc',
     'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Img1.png']
```

Key 11:

```
[i for i in files if i.endswith(config['key11']['files_to_keep'])]
```

Returns:

```
['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Text1.txt', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Doc1.doc']
```

While  Key 12:

```
[i for i in files if i.endswith(config['key11']['files_to_keep'])]
```

Returns:

```
['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Text1.txt',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Doc1.doc',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Img1.png']
```

And Key 13.. is empty :)